# The meaning of "with her small bitchs teats", in "100 Years of Solitude"?

Tags: literature, books

What does "bitchs teats" mean in the the sentence "The adolescent mulatto girl, with her small bitchs teats, was naked on the bed" from the fictional book "100 Years of Solitude"?

The surrounding sentences don't expand on the meaning of this description and mearly add the context of prostitution, and of coercion of both the girl and the protagonist entering the room.

Comment: A bitch is a female dog, and they don't have very big teats. But it's not an expression that has any currency, which is why Márquez has to explicitly specify ***small***.

Comment: The expression simply means that the girl's breasts were similar to those of a female dog. This site doesn't do literary analysis, but I guess the narrator didn't care much for the sight.

Comment: I'd say instead the narrator didn't care much for the person on the bed.

Comment: NB: This book is a translation of _Cien años de soledad_; the (original) book is not in English.

Comment: I’m voting to close this because

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the "s" at the end of "bitch" in the actual (translated) text?  If so, that's an error.  Should be either "small bitch teats" or "small bitch's teats." Or maybe even "small bitches' teats." 
In any case, it's a metaphor, as this adolescent girl did not actually have the mammary glands of a female dog. The narrator apparently thinks her breasts were sized and shaped in such a way as to resemble those of a female dog. Not a fetching picture, but one that presents the girl as a figure to be pitied rather than hated.